# Code prints None and then asks for the input. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code will print `None` and then take the input. If I pass a string in the `print` function, it will print it, followed by `None`, and expect the input. Why does it print `None`?

```
input(print())
```

Comment: Because `print` returns nothing?

Comment: Because the print statement returns None and you're asking for input with whatever print returns

Comment: Should it always print what is returned?even if I write input(print("Please enter an item")), it will print the string and then write None

Comment: @DiptangshuBanik to ask for an input with a text just do this `input("Please enter an item")` print is not to be used in this context.

Comment: `print` prints the string you provide it. Then, it returns `None` because it returns nothing, so it becomes: `input(None)`. `None` is printed because it's the prompt passed to `input`. Just do: `input("Enter something: ")`

Comment: @Andrew Li.. That clears my doubt. It skipped my mind that input can also print a string before it accepts the input.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your guidance. :)

Comment: It is Because you are writing it like that  `input(print())` first prints and then asking for user input. If you want to first ask user input and then print it then you have to write it like this `print(input())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function inside another function:

```
input(print())
```

Therefore, what is inside the brackets will execute first. Since a print statement does not return anything, the `input()` function will not recieve any value, which will look like:

```
input(None)
```

Since the `input()` function prints anything in between its brackets, it prints "None", and following that on the same line, it waits for your input. Then, after you enter a string and hit the enter key, that statement is over, because you do not store it anywhere. If you are in the shell, then it will print the line you input in between apostrophes.

Comment: The confusion was actually faced as in other languages when void is returned, it is not returned as a string/value. So it won't print anything in usual cases. Python plays it pretty differently here. But I get the concept now.

Comment: Yeah, compared to c++, python is a high-level language, and it works differently compared to the former. Anyways, can you please select the tick mark next to my answer? Thanks.